# How can I get VertexCoordinates of this polyhedron?

Tags: polyhedra

I am trying to get VertexCoordinates of this picture of the problem https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2022_AMC_10A_Problems/Problem_21?fbclid=IwAR2bdHwJEpjarZEwope1hYOcnnXqnvzae38Y8ZrfWKCKQunfAuT9s30q32o

I tried with syntax `PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "VertexCoordinates"]` but I do not know the name of Polyhedron. How can I get VertexCoordinates of this polyhedron?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like half of a truncated octahedron.

```
truncOctVertices = PolyhedronData["TruncatedOctahedron", "VertexCoordinates"]
```

will get you all of the vertex coordinates.

We can filter to get just the lower half (z value nonpositive):

```
lowHalfVertices = Select[truncOctVertices, NonPositive@*Last]
```

We can visualize to confirm:

```
ConvexHullMesh[lowHalfVertices]
```

[image]

Comment: How can I get `FaceIndices` by  using`PolyhedronData["lowHalfVertices", "FaceIndices"]`?

Comment: What are you trying to do? FaceIndices would give you insight into Mathematica's representation of a polyhedron, and that seems sort of out of left field based on your original question. Also, once we've turned it into a BoundaryMeshRegion, we have a different representation. There are functions that allow you to extract data from mesh regions: MeshPrimitives, MeshCells, MeshCoordinates, and yes, MeshCellIndex.